# Enumeration error; May not execute

Tags: c#, xna, iteration

Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

I get that error when I run my program.
I have a dictionary and when I modify it I can't enumerate from it.

```
public void Render() {
    foreach (var pair in players ) {
       Main.SpriteBatch.DrawString(Main.BigFont, pair.Key, pair.Value, Color.White);
    }
}
```

I tried modifying it at the value or removing it completely, then it must re-add it.

```
 byte[] data = client.EndReceive(ar, ref ip);
        string str_data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
        string[] coords = str_data.Split(";".ToCharArray());
        if (players.ContainsKey(coords[0])) {
            players.Remove(coords[0]);
        }
        players.Add(coords[0], new Vector2(Int32.Parse(coords[1]), Int32.Parse(coords[2])));
```

Comment: This code means almost nothing, add context to it. BTW: use c# bracket styling; players are not parameter, so why lower letter?

Comment: Java habits, I'm trying to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try to use an ordinary for loop instead of a foreach.
That way you can circumvent the warning, since you're not using the enumeration option.

For a dictionary you would do:

```
List<string/*or other datatype*/> keys = players.Keys.ToList();
for (int i = 0; i < keys.Count; i++)
{
   Main.SpriteBatch.DrawString(Main.BigFont, keys[i], players[keys[i]], Color.White);
}
```

Does this suit your needs?

Comment: I just noticed I still used a foreach in my code example. I changed it so it actually uses a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify (add, update or remove) any collection while you are iterating over it. It is restricted in c#.

You need to modify your code so that you keep any updation on the list seperate. You can keep a seperate record for any changes that you have made during the loop and merge after the loop.e.g

```
var itemsToDelete = new Dictionary<int,Player>();
```

then change your this line

```
    if (players.ContainsKey(coords[0])) {
        players.Remove(coords[0]);
    }
```

to

```
  if (players.ContainsKey(coords[0])) {
        itemsToDelete.Add(coords[0]);
    }
```

then after your loop

```
 foreach (var key in itemsToDelete)
{
   players.Remove(key);
}
```

Comment: Is there any other way to get it so I can do that?

Comment: @BrandonWoolworth I have posted the complete solution.

Comment: Still not working, I think it's because I have an Async UdpClient receiving. It edits the values from there while the Render() method is being called.

Comment: I edit the buffer, then in my update function it updates the players to equal the buffer.. then renders off the players. It doesn't edit the players, but the buffer.. which isn't iterating at any time.

Comment: which method is this players.Remove(coords[0]);?

Answer (score 0):

```
var ToBeDeleted = new List<player>(); //Or whatever type was the list players holding

if (players.ContainsKey(coords[0])) {
            ToBeDeleted.Add(coords[0]);
        }

foreach(var item in ToBeDeleted)
{
players.Remove(item);
}
```